# Microsoft Smooth Streaming on demand without a web server

Tags: iis, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, smooth-streaming, smooth-streaming-player

I'm building a mobile app and the app streams videos using ExoPlayer for Android. My idea is to use smooth streaming for streaming media files.

The app will only stream videos clips that I upload to Amazon S3 bucket myself so I do not need real time encoding or anything.

I'm using Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 to encode my media files.

So my idea is to encode media files manually on my local computer and upload them to S3 bucket and serve via CloudFront.

I have figured out that `.ismc` file contains `manifest` details.

Would this really work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found an answer! This tutorial explains it all.

http://howto-phpjsjqueryawss3ec2cloudfrontfacebooktwittergoogleawsapis.com/how-to-smooth-stream-microsoft-smooth-streaming-files-on-amazon-cloudfront-without-a-web-server/